# How to validate specific ngModel in angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation

> How to validate specific `ngModels` in angular

For Example: I have a table in which, I would like to validate only second row's of `ngModels`

I can validate full form (All `ngModels`) using
`this.myForm.valid`.
and also to validate specific `ngModels` I can loop through `this.myForm.controls` and validate specific one.

Is there another way to validate instead of looping through whole form controls ?

**Full Example Below**

**TS**

```
@ViewChild(NgForm, { static: false }) myForm: NgForm;
employeesData = [{id:"1",firstName:"Tom",lastName:"Cruise",photo:"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/735509975649378305/B81JwLT7.jpg"},{id:"2",firstName:"Maria",lastName:null,photo:"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3424509849/bfa1b9121afc39d1dcdb53cfc423bf12.jpeg"},{id:"3",firstName:"James",lastName:null,photo:"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/664886718559076352/M00cOLrh.jpg"}];

  save() {
    //This helps to validate all fields
    console.log(this.myForm.valid);
    //This contains all form keys - so I can loop through each and validate
    console.log(this.myForm.controls);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employeesData; let i=index">
            <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employee.firstName" [name]="'firstName'+i" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employee.lastName" [name]="'lastName'+i" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
      </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Is there a better way to validate specific ngModels ?

How Could I validate only one row ?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in  stackblitz

Comment: negative vote but no reason given ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was - Check if table's all the `input` in specific row is valid, without looping as we do for whole table, Simply by `tableForm.valid`.

> **So the solution is to have form tag for every table row**

Wait...`<form>` tag is not allowed in `table`, and It will break table layout

> But we can use `ngForm` directive on tr, and can validate specific
>   tr's `ngModels`

**Full Example**

*HTML*

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let header of displayedColumns">{{header}}</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ngForm #sampleForm="ngForm" *ngFor="let ds of dataSource; let i=index">
    <td>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ds.position" [name]="'position'+i" required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ds.name" [name]="'name'+i" required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ds.symbol" [name]="'symbol'+i" required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ds.weight" [name]="'weight'+i" required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button (click)="cnsl(sampleForm)">Cnsl</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*TS*

```
cnsl(frm: NgForm) {
 console.log(frm.controls);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are iterating form fields in for loop. So it is not good to check form is valid or not. Instead you can check those field values with the help of index.

Check this:

HTML:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employeesData; let i=index">
            <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employee.firstName" [name]="'firstName'+i" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employee.lastName" [name]="'lastName'+i" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button (click)="save(i)">Save</button>
      </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

TS:

```
save(i) {
    // console.log(this.employeesData[i])
    // if (!this.myForm.valid) {
    //   alert('Please enter details');
    // } else {
    //   alert('Saved');
    // }

    if(this.employeesData[i].firstName && this.employeesData[i].lastName) {
      alert('Saved');
    }
    else {
      alert('Please enter details');
    }
  }
```

Otherwise you can use Angular Reactive Form with FormArray for dynamic fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
this.ngForm.controls['firstname'].(multiple methods) ->  // all different methods associated with this.
```